# Date Difference Between Two Device Failures

Tags: python, pandas, date, datediff

I am trying to calculate the # of days between `failures`. I'd like to know on each day in the series the # of days passed since the last `failure` where `failure = 1`. There may be anywhere from 1 to 1500 devices.

For Example, Id like my dataframe to look like this (please pull data from url in the second code block. This is just a short example of a larger dataframe.):

```
date        device      failure      elapsed    
10/01/2015  S1F0KYCR    1            0           
10/07/2015  S1F0KYCR    1            7           
10/08/2015  S1F0KYCR    0            0           
10/09/2015  S1F0KYCR    0            0           
10/17/2015  S1F0KYCR    1            11          
10/31/2015  S1F0KYCR    0            0           
10/01/2015  S8KLM011    1            0           
10/02/2015  S8KLM011    1            2           
10/07/2015  S8KLM011    0            0
10/09/2015  S8KLM011    0            0
10/11/2015  S8KLM011    0            0
10/21/2015  S8KLM011    1            20
```

Sample Code:

Edit: Please pull actual data from code block below. The above sample data is an short example. Thanks.

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dsdaveh/device-failure-analysis/master/device_failure.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

df = df.sort_values(by = ['date', 'device'], ascending = True) #Sort by date and device
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y/%m/%d') #format date to datetime
```

This is where I am running into obstacles. However the new column should contain the # of days since last `failure`, where `failure = 1`.

```
test['date'] = 0
for i in test.index[1:]:
    if not test['failure'][i]:
        test['elapsed'][i] = test['elapsed'][i-1] + 1
```

I have also tried

```
fails = df[df.failure==1]
fails.Dates = trues.index #need this because .diff() won't work on the index..
fails.Elapsed = trues.Dates.diff()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `diff` and `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
s = df.groupby(['device', 'failure'])['date'].diff().dt.days.add(1)
s = s.fillna(0)
df['elapsed'] = np.where(df['failure'], s, 0)
```

Output:

```
         Date    Device  Failure  Elapsed
0  2015-10-01  S1F0KYCR        1      0.0
1  2015-10-07  S1F0KYCR        1      7.0
2  2015-10-08  S1F0KYCR        0      0.0
3  2015-10-09  S1F0KYCR        0      0.0
4  2015-10-17  S1F0KYCR        1     11.0
5  2015-10-31  S1F0KYCR        0      0.0
6  2015-10-01  S8KLM011        1      0.0
7  2015-10-02  S8KLM011        1      2.0
8  2015-10-07  S8KLM011        0      0.0
9  2015-10-09  S8KLM011        0      0.0
10 2015-10-11  S8KLM011        0      0.0
11 2015-10-21  S8KLM011        1     20.0
```

**Update**:

Found out the actual data linked in the OP contains **No** device that has more than two *failure* cases, making the final result all zeros (i.e. no second failure has ever happened and thus nothing to calculate for *elapsed*). Using OP's original snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "http://aws-proserve-data-science.s3.amazonaws.com/device_failure.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df = df.sort_values(by = ['date', 'device'], ascending = True) 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

Find if any device has more than 1 failure:

```
df.groupby(['device'])['failure'].sum().gt(1).any()
# False
```

Which actually confirms that the  all zeros in `df['elapsed']` is actually a correct answer :)

If you tweak your data a bit, it does yield *elapsed* just as expected.

```
df.loc[6879, 'device'] = 'S1F0RRB1'
# Making two occurrence of failure for device S1F0RRB1

s = df.groupby(['device', 'failure'])['date'].diff().dt.days.add(1)
s = s.fillna(0)
df['elapsed'] = np.where(df['failure'], s, 0)
df['elapsed'].value_counts()
# 0.0    124493
# 3.0         1
```

Comment: You can shorten this further and dump apply: `df.groupby(['Device', 'Failure'])['Date'].diff().dt.days.where(df['Failure'].astype(bool)).add(1).fillna(0, downcast='infer')`

Comment: Both of these suggestions create an elapsed column of zeros. No date differences are indicated in the column for when a failure occurs. Its just a column of zeros.

Comment: @Starbucks forgot to add the to_datetime part. Pleae give another try ;)

Comment: @Chris Thanks Chris, but I've already identified it as a datetime variable in the first code block. Did you try pulling in the data in the first snippet? I'm still getting all zeros for the elapsed column. Thank you!

Comment: `elapsed` gives me a bunch of `0`s, why?

Comment: @U9-Forward I've updated some analysis on the dataset. Please correct me if there's any loophole :)

Comment: @Starbucks Please check the updated answer and let me know if there's anything I've missed.

Comment: @cs95 Thanks for the advice :) I've changed my original answer a bit according to your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
df['elapsed']=df[df.Failure.astype(bool)].groupby('Device').Date.diff().dt.days.add(1)
df.elapsed.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df
Out[225]: 
         Date    Device  Failure  Elapsed  elapsed
0  2015-10-01  S1F0KYCR        1        0      0.0
1  2015-10-07  S1F0KYCR        1        7      7.0
2  2015-10-08  S1F0KYCR        0        0      0.0
3  2015-10-09  S1F0KYCR        0        0      0.0
4  2015-10-17  S1F0KYCR        1       11     11.0
5  2015-10-31  S1F0KYCR        0        0      0.0
6  2015-10-01  S8KLM011        1        0      0.0
7  2015-10-02  S8KLM011        1        2      2.0
8  2015-10-07  S8KLM011        0        0      0.0
9  2015-10-09  S8KLM011        0        0      0.0
10 2015-10-11  S8KLM011        0        0      0.0
11 2015-10-21  S8KLM011        1       20     20.0
```

Comment: `elapsed` gives me a bunch of `0`s, why?

Comment: @U9-Forward df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y/%m/%d')?

Comment: Yes, i did it with that `pd.to_datetime` thing, tried again and still the same thing

Comment: Probably issue with my old version

Comment: @U9-Forward what version you have for pandas

Comment: When i use 0.24 i just go to repl.it, too lazy to update :-)